# Extra space character at start of paragraph after code block

Tags: support, markdown, jsfiddle

In some cases, paragraphs after a code block are given an extra space character at the start.

You can see this in the image below--the paragraph beginning with "You" is fine, but the one beginning with "Here" is indented (instead of being next to the drawn-in red line):

[image: Improper indent example]

This extra space character is *not*, at least to the eye, in the original markup.

You may [see the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788850/js-shouldnt-this-be-written-better-one-function-vs-multiples/13794590#13794590) if you like.

Comment: Please **do not add a new question** to an already existing question...

Comment: You can insert such characters by copy and paste or by holding the ALT key pressed then pressing the ASCII code in the numbers to the right of the keyboard. e.g. ALT+255 is   such a space. ALT+1 is ☺ etc.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Do you mean that you would prefer I open an entirely new MSO question to ask where such a character might have come from?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I've been doing Alt + Numpad numbers> for at least 25 years, and am very sure I didn't accidentally type anything like that in this case.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA That seems a total waste... when it is a logical extension of the same question. In fact, such a question, divorced from the context, seems like it would be closed as "too localized". But it is a reasonable question.

Comment: Time for "status-unreproducible" tag...

Comment: @ErikE I appreciate that you did not choose my answer due to the fact that I rolled back your question. But extending a question with a new question (even if it is an extension of the original question) is not appreciated on the Stack Exchange.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA It's not the rollback... I really struggled with which answer to pick (and in fact tried to pick yours before the 10-minute limit, and did upvote your answer). Ultimately, I chose the more complete answer which included not only telling me *what* was going on, but *why*. If I'm not allowed to alter my question to add "why" in addition to the "what" (when I didn't know I needed to ask *why* earlier) then I think that's silly. I didn't totally change the question, I didn't ask a *new*, completely add-on or unrelated question. I do see your point and need to think about it.

Comment: @ErikE Considering your follow-up question was directly related, there was really no harm in adding it, don't worry.

Comment: @TimStone yes, but that can change the meaning of answers. For example mine. and cause people to give me a downvote because I did not answer the question "fully".

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Doesn't look like you have a down vote at the moment...

Comment: @amanaP Let's ask Tim. If he says he wouldn't have answered *why* without my add-on question, I will give you the accepted answer.

Comment: lol no I do not. because the question was not changed ^_^ @TimStone .

Comment: @TimStone What do you say to my last comment please?

Comment: @ErikE I don't care. give it to him. Just think next time. rep is meaningless to me

Comment: @amanaP I do think, all the time. No worries there. You know, I have plenty of times added an answer to a question that *already had an exactly correct answer*, and gotten better voting from it--because I added value through explanation, more code, jsfiddle or sqlfiddle examples, stylistic considerations, and so on. Next time I'll try to avoid an edit adding a blatant question ending with a question mark. I'll just hint, or put it as a comment on the "less rounded" question I'd like to see filled out more.

Comment: @ErikE Heh, he beat me to answering first specifically because I was trying to figure where it might have come from, but it's not something I'd fret over either way. :P

Comment: @TimStone Thank you! I feel vindicated. Though if I had just waited, your answer would have surfaced anyway. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a zero-width space in your post, which I removed:

[image: zero-width space in editor]

Presumably you copy and pasted the code directly from your jsFiddle, since I'm able to reproduce the trailing zero-width space  when doing so. This traces back to a bug in CodeMirror, as detailed in [this report against jsFiddle](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-docs-alpha/issues/163).

Fun fact: This same issue apparently bit me [some time ago](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/query.js#66) when doing Data Explorer work. Good to know it was a problem with CodeMirror.

Comment: FREEHAND CIRCLES!

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra character in there:

[image: extra]

Comment: 6666.  Nice quads

Comment: Aha! I could not see this space character. After your explanation I was able to find it by cursoring through on the line *above* "Here". I pressed right-arrow but the insertion point didn't appear to move, proving some zero-width was in fact there. Somehow I got a strange character in there, and because it was on the line *above* "Here" I didn't find it.

Comment: @SamIam haha thanks ^_^

Comment: Sorry but I just ruined your 6666!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd arrrg and i did not screenshot it :-P

Comment: I can undo my vote then! ;-)

Comment: Naaahh it is ok ;-) @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: I'm just gonna screw with the 6676